# Resharper or nUnit test count for reflective tests

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I have a a number of tests based upon reflection.  The reflective test work on a given assembly for a give type, i.e. look in the service.dll for everything based upon IService for example.  I have done it this why because I need to pipe reference types into the tests that I can't do with TestCase attribution.  The code basically looks like the following:

```
    public static void TestRunnerforTypeList(Type baseType, Func<Type, string, bool> excluder, Action<Type, string> mockResolver, Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, Mock>> mocks, Action<dynamic, Type> assertor, string methodName)
    {
        foreach (var type in GetTypesToTest(baseType))
        {
            if (excluder(type, methodName)) continue;
            dynamic objectToTest = CreateInstance(type, mocks);
            mockResolver(type, methodName);
            assertor(objectToTest, type);
        }
    }
```

A call to this would look like the following:

```
    [Test]
    public void Positive_outcome_for_Get()
    {
        GeneralTestRunner.TestRunnerforTypeList(typeof(IService<,,>),
                                            _serviceFactoryContext.ExcludeTypeForMethod,
                                            _serviceFactoryContext.ResolvePositiveMockSetup, 
                                            _mocks, 
                                            (service, type) => Assert.IsNotNull(service.Get(1)),
                                            "Get");
    }
```

It's simple assertion but you get the idea.  This way I get the benefit of TestCase attribution but with reference types, like mocks, being piped in.

However I have other places where I use TestCase attibution and Resharper picks up these up and increases the number of test in the test session, the refective ones don't.

My question is there a way of telling Resharper (or nUnit) that the number has increased every time the above assertor action is called?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is with Resharper 6 and dropping the reflective aspect and use a TestCaseSource attribute.  The TestCaseSource would point to a static IEnumerable yielding a factory reference type for each test.  See documentation below:

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5

The only issue compared to the question implementation is the reflective test will fail if programmer doesn't create mocks for the instance creator, however the type is still picked up (if it's in the same assembly).  Therefore if a lazy programmer creates a new type based upon IService (for example) with no tests, if fails, out the box.